# Quando ocorre o Stack Overflow?

Tags: c, memória, stack

Uma pergunta que tem tudo haver com o nome desse site.

---

Sabemos que um dos exemplos, mais usados, para demonstrar a pilha de execução de um programa é a recursividade. Uma função recursiva deve ter: condição de parada e a recursão deve resolver uma instância menor do mesmo problema.

Na execução as chamadas recursivas serão empilhadas e depois desempilhadas (executadas), do menor caso para o maior, até retornar o valor final.

Se **não existir condição de parada** ou a **chamada recursiva não for para uma instância menor**, o programa entra em *loop* infinito e ocorre ***Stack Overflow***.

Dado o código a seguir desenvolvido em C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int fat(int n);

int main()
{
int n;

printf("Calculo de FATORIAL\n");

printf("Entre com um numero:");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("Fatorial:%d",fat(n));

getch();
return 0;
}

int fat(int n)
{
 if (n==1)
    return(1);

 return(n * fat(n-1));
        
}
```

Como seria a pilha de execução de 4!, por exemplo?

Se não houvesse condição de parada, o programa iria empilhar até ocorrer estouro de pilha. Em que momento isso ocorreria, ou seja, qual o tamanho dessa pilha?

Comment: Não sei se entendi. Entendi o problema. Mas qual seria sua dúvida? O que você quer saber com esse "quando"?

Comment: Editei a pergunta para ficar mais clara. Em resumo gostaria de mostrar a pilha de execução para 4! de forma didática e saber quando ocorre estouro de pilha, ou seja, qual o tamanho dessa pilha.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Primeiro tenha certeza que entende [o que é a pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Ela é uma porção de memória previamente alocada pela aplicação que vai sendo preenchida conforme a necessidade das funções (ou escopos). Conforme a execução vai entrando em novos escopos ele vai reservando espaço (na parte já alocada) para todas variáveis locais contidas nele (isto é chamado de *stack frame*). Quando sai do escopo este espaço é liberado pelo movimentação de um ponteiro (*stack pointer*) que indica onde está o topo da pilha (a base dele na memória é indicado pelo *base pointer* e é usado para calcular o endereço real porque o acesso na pilha é sempre relativo ao seu início e não a memória toda). Então o espaço vai sendo usado em um efeito sanfona.

[image: Stack Frame]

Se o código entrar em uma sequência grande de escopos - isto ocorre principalmente em chamada de funções - os espaços vão sendo reservados e não vão sendo liberados, até que comece sair destes escopos. A pilha tem um espaço finito, então uma hora pode não ter mais espaço alocado para reservar, e o estouro de pilha ocorre.

Isto pode ocorrer principalmente em duas situações:

- Alocações de dados muito grandes em variáveis locais (sem apontamento) - o que nunca é recomendado - que mesmo em uma única chamada de uma função pode reservar quase toda pilha alocada, deixando em um estado de quase estouro;
- Fazer chamadas recursivas sem parada, ou com parada muito distante, conforme colocado na pergunta, o que é mais comum.

No caso da recursão, mesmo com uma única variável simples de baixo consumo de memória é possível, em milhares de execuções, estourar a pilha (alguns compiladores conseguem fazer uma otimização [eliminando a recursividade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184494/101)).

Neste caso a função `fat()` terá sempre que reservar 4 bytes (tipicamente) para o parâmetro `n` (que é uma variável local) e provavelmente mais 4 bytes para o retorno da função chamada. Se não tem nada que pare isto vai acumulando estes bytes indefinidamente em cada chamada.

O tamanho da pilha varia e, em geral, pode ser determinado no momento da criação do executável. O padrão usado pode variar também, mas é comum que a pilha tenha 1MB no Windows.

Quando vai criar *threads* uma nova pilha é criada. Isso pode ser muito, e em alguns casos, pouco. É possível controlar isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Só 1M? E o restante do espaço que está sendo ocupado na memória ram?

Comment: @SamuelIves A pilha esta na RAM. E por isso que pode ter o StackOverflow no sentido que não tem limite "fisica" na pilha. Ou seja, como explica Maniero, se vc usa recursividade, o stack pointer pode ir ate perturbar parte da RAM usada por seu variaveis, o mesmo o codigo. Num PC ou um Mac, geralemente, tem espaço o suficiente. Mas no caso do Arduino por exemplo, o fenomeno do "stack overflow" pode acontecer e depois de um momento vc inicia a ter variaveis destruidas.