# Qual é a duração dos dados alocados em funções?

Tags: javascript, funções, memória, alocação, stack

Em uma linguagem, (não sei se tem diferença em outras, mas pode considerar JavaScript) quando tenho essa situação:

```
function a() {
    b();
}

function b() {
    c();
}

function c() {
    d();
}

function d() {
    e();
}

function e() {
    f();
}

function f() {

}
```

O que acontece com as coisas que estão sendo criadas dentro dos métodos? À medida que vai executando ele vai liberando a memória ou ele mantém até o método `F` executar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro nada está sendo executado dentro destas funções. Não há a alocação de memória, portando não tem o que ser liberado.

Se o exemplo tivesse alguma variável sendo alocada, ao final da execução de cada função, o conteúdo é liberado. Não o espaço ocupado na memória, já que a memória está pré-alocada. Variáveis locais de funções são colocadas na [pilha (*stack*)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). Então cada chamada de função vai subindo na pilha, e no final vai voltando à posição original.

Então tudo o que for alocado em `a, b, c, d, e` será mantido lá enquanto estas funções estão em execução, elas só delegaram temporariamente para outra função. Conforme cada uma delas vai terminando vai liberando. O nome pilha é justamente para identificar bem isto. Você não pode liberar o que está embaixo, pra tirar da pilha alguma coisa que não está no topo só tirando o que está acima.

A pilha existe independente de usar ou não (é impossível não usá-la em qualquer coisa que faça algo minimamente útil). O espaço alocado para a pilha é fixo, usando ou não. Se ultrapassar espaço da pilha ocorre o famoso [*stack overflow*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101).

De uma maneira geral todas as linguagens trabalham assim.

Se houver alguma alocação no *heap* (ver *link* acima) esta não será liberada. A estratégia de liberação de memória do *heap* varia de linguagem para linguagem. Algumas exigem que o programador faça isto, algumas fazem de forma mais ou menos automática, outras fazem isto de forma perfeita, e ainda outras fazem até certo ponto. Em geral [vai no *heap* o que é grande demais para a pilha ou que precisa sobreviver ao fim da função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Em relação a não ter nada dentro dos métodos, é devido a ser só um exemplo. Bigown, então, caso eu quisesse que essa pilha não fosse mantida, eu teria que basicamente, não ter uma pilha, certo? Para um caso que eu precise que uma função execute outra, eu poderia usar da abordagem de maquinas de estados para conseguir o mesmo resultado que essa pilha, evitando assim o "problema" de uma função ter que esperar o resultado de outra para conseguir liberar o que precisa, certo?

Comment: Melhorei a resposta. Leia os *links* passados para entender melhor. A pergunta e o exemplo estão bem descasados, dá para entender o quer quer mas ele não representa bem o que está sendo perguntado, só confunde. Máquina de estado é outra coisa e não parece ter a ver com esta pergunta, se era a intenção, precisa fazer outra pergunta. E esperar ou não a execução da outra depende do que deseja. Faz sentido, mas não esperar a outra não significa que ela deixa de executar. A pilha será usada de qualquer jeito. E se não soube o que está fazendo pode comprometê-la. Ou pode prejudicar a performance.

Comment: @PauloGustavo No caso específico do JS a coisa é um pouco mais complicada. No seu exemplo não tem muito segredo, mas se houver [closures](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859) tem coisas que podem ficar "vivas" indefinidamente (vivas = não removidas pelo coletor de lixo).