# Por que esse método gera java.lang.StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, exceção

O seguinte código gera isso:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at modelo.Secao.eleitores(Secao.java:67)
```

E eu não sei porque.

[image: Linha do erro]

Comment: Onde é a linha 67??

Comment: O problema provavelmente está em outro lugar. Saber a linha do erro provavelmente ajudar entender onde é esse lugar. Esse erro, escondido como se apresenta, não é simples ser resolvido, e provavelmente ocorre porque a arquitetura da aplicação está bem errada. Seria bom ler isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101

Comment: @diegofm A linha 67 da classe Secao simplesmente é: return eleitores;

Comment: ok, vou ler. Valeu!

Comment: Se o código onde gera o erro nem está presente não dá para responder a pergunta adequadamente. É um pouco estranho o erro correr nessa linha, mas pode ser. Se for o problema está em outro lugar mesmo.

Comment: Adicione um [mcve], para que seja possivel simular seu código e o problema.

Comment: Vc está chamando um método dentro dele mesmo? Está ai seu problema, `eleitores()` não possui nenhuma condição de parada, logo será chamado infinitas vezes. :)

Comment: Coloque o código em texto e não em imagem, estou editando e tirando toda parte que não tem nenhum relação com o problema. meus comentários eram baseados na pergunta original que nada tinha a ver com o problema. Agora a questão é saber se está chamando o mesmo método dentro dele por engano ou se há necessidade de fazer isso. Se tem necessidade precisa resolver a condição de termino. Se foi sem querer, tem que arrumar e chamar o correto. Do jeito atual não só dá erro, mas não faz sentido, para ser útil deveria ter alguma alteração de estado ou pelo menos chamar outro comportamento.

Comment: Putz, realmente sobraram dois parênteses naquela linha. Precisei tirar e resolver mais uma condição no método setSecaoEleitor.  Victor Stafusa: eu tinha apresentado um método inteiro, que era onde eu chamava eleitores(), daí respondi a minha própria pergunta com essa imagem, pq o pessoal disse que precisava da linha 67, que era onde acusava o erro. Descupa a noobagem, não sei o que aconteceu com o código da pergunta, eu só RESPONDI a pergunta com a imagem. Esse site é realmente ótimo pelo pessoal ter a intenção de ajudar, mas a interface.... Valeu pessoal! *foi a primeira pergunta no site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe o código:

```
ArrayList<Eleitor> eleitores(){
    return eleitores();
}
```

Vamos ver o que este método `eleitores()` faz:

Primeiro, ele chama o método `eleitores()`, que por sua vez vai chamar o método `eleitores()`, que por sua vez vai chamar o método `eleitores()`, que por sua vez vai chamar o método `eleitores()`, que por sua vez vai chamar o método `eleitores()`, ... BUUUUM! `StackOverflowError`.

Propor uma solução deve ser algo fácil, mas fico um tanto incerto e duvidoso de fazer isso porque você não postou o seu código inteiro da classe `Secao`, e preferiu postar uma droga de uma imagem contendo um pedaço do código, ao invés de postar o código propriamente dito [(comportamento esse que todos nessa comunidade unanimemente odeiam)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5149/132). Dessa forma, eu não tenho como ter certeza acerca do que mais há na sua classe `Secao` que serviria para resolver o seu problema. Além disso, o sistema de busca vai ter mais dificuldade com a sua questão, vez que o conteúdo de imagens não pode ser indexado. Entretanto, apesar disso tudo, eu acho que o que você queria é isso:

```
ArrayList<Eleitor> eleitores() {
    return eleitores;
}
```

A única diferença aqui é que o valor retornado não é sucedido pelos parênteses. A ideia aqui é retornar o conteúdo de uma variável, e não chamar um método. Essa confusão aconteceu porque você tinha dado o nome do método com o mesmo nome da sua variável, o que é algo que o Java permite, mas é uma péssima prática de programação, vez que é algo confuso que tende a criar problemas exatamente como este que você está tendo. Para não sofrer com esse tipo de chatice, sugiro fazer isso:

```
public List<Eleitor> getEleitores() {
    return eleitores;
}
```

Aqui eu mudei o nome do método para `getEleitores()`, deixando o nome da variável como `eleitores`. Dessa forma, se você usar acidentalmente `eleitores()` (com parênteses) ou `getEleitores` (sem parênteses), o resultado vai ser um erro de compilação óbvio ao invés de algo que compila, mas que dá pau na hora de rodar.

Além disso, eu coloquei o método como público porque acho que você se esqueceu do modificador e não tem interesse em usar a visibilidade de pacote. Também mudei o tipo de retorno de `ArrayList` para `List` vez que os princípios de orientação a objetos dizem para codificar para uma interface, e com `List` em lugar de `ArrayList`, a sua API depende de uma interface ao invés de uma implementação concreta em particular dela.

Comment: Agradeço a todos que tentaram ajudar. Realmente sobraram dois parênteses na linha 67 (valeu renan). Fiquei um tempão e nem percebi, bem burro :s hehe

Comment: @RamnaSidharta Se esta resposta te ajudou e resolveu o problema, marque-a como correta clicando no ✅ verde abaixo dos números da votação. Obrigado. :)