# O que é segmentation fault?

Tags: c, c++, memória

Esse erro ocorre com frequência em códigos com problemas. Não vejo ele ocorrendo em outras linguagens. Por que ele ocorre? O que significa?

Comment: Sempre me perguntei sobre isso, já vi acontecendo esse erro em PHP quando você roda um código na linha de comando que gera uma recursão infinita.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters provavelmente é erro do PHP :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Isso ocorre por acessar um ponto da memória não autorizado para sua aplicação.

Quando sua aplicação está rodando, o sistema operacional libera acesso à memória virtual. Ao contrário do que muita gente pensa, você não tem acesso à memória física (RAM) diretamente, na verdade pode ser que nem esteja na RAM. É um problema do sistema operacional colocar onde quiser, ele organiza a memória como quiser. Ele colocará seu código, área estática de dados, a pilha e depois vai alocando outros trechos dinamicamente conforme a necessidade, o [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). A memória física nem costuma estar em sequência, mas parece estar. Quando sua aplicação acessa parece que a memória toda do computador é dela, por isso é chamada de memória virtual, os endereços não são os físicos. Claro que a memória precisa estar reservada para seu uso.

Então qualquer endereço que seja acessado pela aplicação e não estava reservada é considerado um endereço inválido. Assim há uma proteção às outras aplicações. A memória é dividida em segmentos, então a tentativa de acessar um segmento que não lhe pertence causa uma falha de segmentação.

Em C ou C++ é comum ter este tipo de problema porque o uso dos ponteiros é muito livre e direto. É relativamente fácil fazer uma variável ponteiro ter um valor inválido. Principalmente por **esquecer de inicializar o ponteiro**, mas também:

- por fazer uma aritmética errada ou pegar valor aleatório (*wild pointer*),
- tratar um outro dado como se fosse ponteiro,
- usar um endereço que era existente e não é mais (*dangling pointer*),
- [stack overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101),
- acessar endereço além de uma sequencia (*array*), que em outras linguagens é o *out of range*, especialmente em *string* sem terminador,
- modificar área estática, especialmente literais *strings*,
- entre outros.

É muito comum ocorrer um *segmentation fault* por causa de um [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101) deixado no código.

Mas sabe qual é o endereço que mais causa esse problema? É o 0, ou seja, o [nulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101). Nesse ponto é igual à exceção *Null Pointer* ou *Null Reference* de outras linguagens. Essas linguagens não são tão liberais com o uso de ponteiros, costumam gerenciar o acesso à memória, mas costumam permitir que um objeto possa ser nulo. Linguagens mais modernas estão evitando isso e só deixando o nulo ocorrer por escolha do programador onde faça sentido.

Hoje os compiladores possuem opções para ajudar identificar potenciais problemas de ponteiros e nem deixam fazer operações que criarão problemas. Existem ferramentas extras de análise estática ou dinâmica que ajudam ainda mais.

Aparecendo esse erro já comece ver seus ponteiros, o problema está em um deles.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).