# Conversor de bases - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

Estou tentando programar um programa simples que leia um número em base dez e o converta para binário e cheguei ao seguinte código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    int c = 1;
    scanf("%d", n);
    while(n>=c){
        int digit = (n/c)%2;
        printf("%d", digit);
        c *= 2;
    }

}
```

Eu estou ciente de que o número será printado ao contrário, o meu problema é que, depois de compilar o código (que acontece sem nenhum erro), o programa sempre crasha quando tento abrir. Quando usei um compilador online, no entanto, o output que tive foi "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Alguém pode me explicar o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é segmentation fault?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177185/o-que-%c3%a9-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde @Christus,

O erro mencionado por você: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, acontece quando você tenta acessar uma memória indevidamente no seu programa, por exemplo: Se você aloca um vetor de 10 espaços e tenta acessar `vet[100]` sua aplicação será finalizada como medida de proteção, para que não possa ser feita nenhuma alteração nos programas que estão executando. Mais detalhes sobre o `Segmentation fault` podem ser encontrados nessa [reposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177185/o-que-%C3%A9-segmentation-fault).

Rodei o seu código em um [compilador online C](http://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler#) e ele acusou o uso indevido do `scanf()`.

Em C utilizamos o `&` para passar o endereço de variáveis a terem seus valores alterados, no caso do exemplo:

`scanf("%d", n);`

Passa a ser:

`scanf("%d", &n);`

E depois de corrigir funcionou normalmente, exceto pelo fato do binário estar ao contrário.

Abraços!