# Segmentation Fault na strcat()

Tags: c, string, memória, falha-de-segmentação

Recentemente comecei a aprender sobre a função `strcat()` e desenvolvi o código abaixo, porém estou me deparando com um erro de *segmentation fault*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
   char a[] ="sweet ";
   char b[] = "home ";
   char c[] = "alabama ";

   strcat(a, b);
   strcat(a, c);

   printf("%s", a);
  return 0;
}
```

Por que esse erro acontece? Como evitá-lo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quase tudo o que quer saber está em:

- [Ponteiro de string não funciona como o esperado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160692/101)
- [Se array é o mesmo que ponteiro, por que um precisa ser copiado para uma variável e outro não precisa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181609/101)
- [De onde vem o espaço na memória necessário para cada elemento em um array de strings em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/446248/101)
- [O que é segmentation fault?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177185/101)

Acompanhe os *links* contidos nelas.

Em resumo, está tentando escrever em uma área protegida da memória. O valor da variável `a` aponta para um endereço de memória estática, ou seja, que não pode ser escrita, que é onde fica todos literais *string*. Esses textos que usou não ficam [na *stack* ou no *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) que são os locais onde pode escrever algo. Para usar a função [`strcat()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) precisa prover um local onde o destino possa ser escrito.

Para evitar o erro deve criar uma área da memória na pilha ou no *heap* que caiba o texto que pretende colocar e aí copiar os dados que deseja para lá, conforme outras perguntas já foram feitas e respondidas.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pela resposta vai ajudar bastante.