# Como reiniciar o loop para o jogador jogar mais de uma vez independente de acertar a resposta ou não

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

print('='*20)
print('JOGO DA FORCA')
print('='*20)
print('Bem vindo ao Jogo da Forca! Vamos começar!')

nome = input("Digite o seu nome: ")
palavra = ('uva','oi')
palavra_forca = random.choice(palavra)

digitadas = []
acertos = []
erros = 0


while True:
    senha = ""
    for letra in palavra_forca:
        senha += letra if letra in acertos else "_ "
    print(senha)
    if senha == palavra_forca:
        print(f"{nome} acertou!")
        break
    tentativa = input("\nDigite uma letra:").lower().strip()
    if tentativa in digitadas:
        print("Você já tentou esta letra!")
        continue
    else:
        digitadas += tentativa
        if tentativa in palavra_forca:
            acertos += tentativa
        else:
            erros += 1
            print("Você errou!")
            print()
    print("X==:==\nX  :   ")
    print("X  O   " if erros >= 1 else "X")
    linha2 = ""
    if erros == 2:
        linha2 = "  |   "
    elif erros == 3:
        linha2 = " \|   "
    elif erros >= 4:
        linha2 = " \|/ "
    print("X%s" % linha2)
    linha3 = ""
    if erros == 5:
        linha3 += " /     "
    elif erros >= 6:
        linha3 += " / \ "
    print("X%s" % linha3)
    print("X\n===========")
    if erros == 6:
        print(f"{nome} foi enforcado!")
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

Se quer que o *loop* continue, basta não interrompê-lo. No seu caso, você está usando `break`, que interrompe o *loop*, então basta não usá-lo (ou só usá-lo quando realmente tiver que encerrar). Não ficou claro se deve "continuar para sempre", mas uma sugestão seria perguntar ao usuário se quer continuar jogando. Algo assim:

```
while True:
    # lógica do jogo

    if senha == palavra_forca:
        print(f"{nome} acertou!")
        if input('Jogar novamente? S/N').lower() == 'n':
            break
```

**Mas só isso não é o suficiente**, pois ao reiniciar o jogo você tem que setar novamente as variáveis `palavra_forca`, `digitadas`, `acertos` e `erros` (já que é um novo jogo começando). Eu sugiro criar uma função que retorna essas informações "zeradas", e aí você pode usá-la para setar as variáveis nos 2 casos que ela é necessária (quando o jogador acerta ou quando se esgotam as chances). Ficaria assim:

```
# ler o nome, etc...

def setup_inicial():
    return (random.choice(palavra), [], [], 0)

palavra_forca, digitadas, acertos, erros = setup_inicial()

while True:
    senha = ""
    for letra in palavra_forca:
        senha += letra if letra in acertos else "_ "
    print(senha)
    if senha == palavra_forca:
        print(f"{nome} acertou!")
        if input('Jogar novamente? S/N: ').lower() == 'n':
            break
        else: # "zera" as variáveis, iniciando um novo jogo as variáveis
            palavra_forca, digitadas, acertos, erros = setup_inicial()
            continue # aqui ele vai para a próxima iteração do loop, ignorando o restante abaixo

    # ler a tentativa, imprimir o homem enforcado, etc...

    if erros == 6:
        print(f"{nome} foi enforcado!")
        if input('Jogar novamente? S/N: ').lower() == 'n':
            break
        else: # "zera" as variáveis, iniciando um novo jogo as variáveis
            palavra_forca, digitadas, acertos, erros = setup_inicial()
```

---

Ao usar `break`, ele sai do `while True` e continua executando o código (caso tenha algo depois do `while`). Mas se a ideia é simplesmente sair do programa, você pode usar [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit). Nesse caso, daria para usar uma função um pouco mais "esperta" para verificar se foi digitado "s" ou "n" (pois do jeito que está acima, qualquer coisa diferente de "n" faz com que o jogo continue).

E já que está usando [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (por exemplo, em `print(f"{nome} acertou!")`), não precisa usar `%` para imprimir `linha2` e `linha3`, use a mesma coisa nos respectivos `print`'s.

Também usei [*raw string literals*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708) para que a `\` seja interpretada corretamente, já que em strings esse caractere é usado para sequências de escape, como por exemplo o `\n` que indica uma quebra de linha (mas no seu caso não parece dar problema porque coincidiu de não ter uma sequência de escape, de qualquer forma, coloquei abaixo também).

E a variável que guarda todas as palavras possíveis poderia se chamar `palavras` (no plural). Ao chamá-la de `palavra` (no singular), pode passar a impressão - errada - de que ela só tem uma palavra. Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

Enfim, ficaria assim:

```
import random
import sys

print('='*20)
print('JOGO DA FORCA')
print('='*20)
print('Bem vindo ao Jogo da Forca! Vamos começar!')

nome = input("Digite o seu nome: ")
palavras = ('uva','oi')

def setup_inicial():
    return (random.choice(palavras), [], [], 0)

def continua_jogando():
    while True:
        opcao = input('Jogar novamente? s/n ').lower()
        if opcao == 'n': # se digitou "n", sai do jogo (interrompe o programa)
            sys.exit(0)
        if opcao == 's': # se digitou "s", retorna o setup inicial com as variáveis "zeradas"
            return setup_inicial()
        # não digitou "s" nem "n", imprime a mensagem e pede que digite novamente
        print('Digite "s" ou "n"')

palavra_forca, digitadas, acertos, erros = setup_inicial()

while True:
    senha = ""
    for letra in palavra_forca:
        senha += letra if letra in acertos else "_ "
    print(senha)
    if senha == palavra_forca:
        print(f"{nome} acertou!")
        palavra_forca, digitadas, acertos, erros = continua_jogando()
        continue # como vai reiniciar o jogo, use "continue" para ir direto para a próxima iteração do while, ignorando o que está abaixo

    tentativa = input("\nDigite uma letra:").lower().strip()
    if tentativa in digitadas:
        print("Você já tentou esta letra!")
        continue
    else:
        digitadas += tentativa
        if tentativa in palavra_forca:
            acertos += tentativa
        else:
            erros += 1
            print("Você errou!\n")

    print("X==:==\nX  :   ")
    print("X  O   " if erros >= 1 else "X")
    linha2 = ""
    if erros == 2:
        linha2 = "  |   "
    elif erros == 3:
        linha2 = r" \|   "
    elif erros >= 4:
        linha2 = r" \|/ "
    print(f"X{linha2}")
    linha3 = ""
    if erros == 5:
        linha3 += " /     "
    elif erros >= 6:
        linha3 += r" / \ "
    print(f"X{linha3}")
    print("X\n===========")
    if erros == 6:
        print(f"{nome} foi enforcado!")
        palavra_forca, digitadas, acertos, erros = continua_jogando()
```

---

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/458005/112052) (que foi apagada) está sugerindo usar [recursão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052) (criar uma função e chamá-la dentro dela mesma).

Apesar de "funcionar", não é a solução ideal. Cada chamada recursiva [vai sendo empilhada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/95826/112052), e depois de um determinado número de iterações, ela pode acabar estourando a pilha ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/oJohIt) um exemplo).

Já se você usar um *loop* simples e interrompê-lo (seja com `break` ou com `sys.exit`), não há esse risco. O programa pode iterar quantas vezes quiser que não ocorrerá o estouro de pilha.

Answer (score -1):

Coloque todo esse loop dentro de outro while True:

```
while True:
  palavra = ('uva','oi')
  palavra_forca = random.choice(palavra)

  digitadas = []
  acertos = []
  erros = 0
  while True:
    senha = ''
```

Comment: Desse jeito não vai dar certo, no final ele vai ficar repetindo sem parar que ele ganhou ou perdeu