# Meu programa roda normalmente mas aparece uma mensagem de erro envolvendo a função main()

Tags: c, funções

Decidi fazer um projeto para criação de conta bancaria, o programa roda normalmente no Code::Blocks, porém no VS Code aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro envolvendo a função main:

> ```
> Banco.c: In function 'criar': Banco.c:43:16: warning: implicit declaration of function 'main' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>         case 9: main();
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 100
int esc1,esc2;
int u=0;
char nome[MAX],sobrenome[MAX],data[MAX],email[MAX],cpf[MAX],tel[MAX],contatip[MAX],esc3[MAX],esc4[MAX];

int criar()
{
    
    printf("\n A seguir voce ira adicionar informacoes para a criacao da sua conta. Aperte qualquer tecla para continuar ou caso queira voltar ao menu digite 9\n\n");
        scanf("%i",&esc2);
           getchar();

    printf("\nDigite seu nome e sobrenome: ");
        scanf("%s%s",&nome,&sobrenome);
            fflush(stdin);

    printf("\nDigite sua data de nascimento: ");
        fgets(data,MAX,stdin);
    printf("\nDigite seu email: ");
        fgets(email,MAX,stdin);
    printf("\nDigite seu CPF: ");
        fgets(cpf,MAX,stdin);
    printf("\nDigite seu numero de telefone: ");
        fgets(tel,MAX,stdin);

   printf("\n1.Corrente\n\n2.Poupanca\n\n");
        scanf("%s",&contatip);
        if(strcmp(contatip , "1")==0){
            strcpy(contatip, "Corrente");}
        else (strcmp(contatip,"2")==0);{
                strcpy(contatip, "Poupanca");}

   printf("Conta criada com sucesso !!!\n\nDigite 8 para sair da aplicacao ou 9 para voltar ao menu.\n\n");
        scanf("%i",&esc2);

    u = 1;

   switch(esc2)
   {
       case 9: main();
   }
}

int ver()
{
    if(u == 1){
        printf("%s %s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", nome,sobrenome,data,email,cpf,tel,contatip);
            printf("\nGostaria de voltar ao menu? S/N ");
                scanf("%s",esc3);}
                    if(strcmp(esc3,"s")==0){
                        main();}
                            else if(strcmp(esc3, "S")==0){
                                 main();}


        else if(u == 0)
            printf("\nVoce nao possui uma conta, gostaria de criar uma? S/N\n\n");
                scanf("%s",&esc3);

            if(strcmp(esc3, "s")==0)
                criar();
               else if(strcmp(esc3, "S")==0)
                    criar();
}

int mudar()
{
    if(u==1){
    printf("\nAtualize o seu nome e sobrenome: ");
        scanf("%s%s",nome,sobrenome);
    printf("\nAtualize sua data de nascimento: ");
        scanf("%s",&data);
    printf("\nAtualize seu email: ");
        scanf("%s",&email);
    printf("\nAtualize seu CPF: ");
        scanf("%s",&cpf);
    printf("\nAtualize seu numero de telefone: ");
        scanf("%s",&tel);

   printf("\n1.Corrente\n\n2.Poupanca\n\n");
        scanf("%s",&contatip);
        if(strcmp(contatip , "1")==0)
            strcpy(contatip, "Corrente");
        else if (strcmp(contatip,"2")==0);
                    strcpy(contatip, "Poupanca");

                printf("Pronto, suas mudancas foram salvas, gostaria de voltar ao menu? S/N \n");
                    scanf("%s",&esc4);
                if(strcmp(esc4,"s")==0)
                        main();}


    else if(u==0){
        printf("Voce nao possui uma conta em nosso banco, gostaria de criar uma agora? S/N\n");
            scanf("%s",esc4);
        if(strcmp(esc4,"s")==0)
            criar();}
        else if(strcmp(esc4,"S")==0)
                criar();}

int main()
{
    int esc;

    printf("   Bem vindo ao menu ! ! ! \n\n1.Criar uma nova conta\n2.Ver informacao da conta\n3.Atualizar informacao da conta\n4.Excluir conta\n6.Sair\n\n");
        scanf("%i",&esc1);

    switch(esc1)
    {
        case 1: criar();
        break;

        case 2: ver();
        break;

        case 3: mudar();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso é só um *warning* de um compilador mais cuidadoso do que o que estava usando. Antes seria bom dar uma lida em [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101). Então funciona, mas não é adequado, em qualquer compilador, só que alguns nem te avisam disso, outros avisam. *Warnings* não impedem a compilação mas são erros.

Já adianto que o código é confuso e usa várias outras coisas que não são boas em programação, portanto eu escolheria outro método ou fontes melhores para seu estudo. Algumas delas sequer funcionam em certos compiladores (algumas silenciosamente).

O problema aí é que chama uma função que será declarada só depois, então o compilador nem tem certeza se a chamada está correta.

Mas não é dito aí sobre o problema mais grave. Ele nem deve causar problemas em exercício, o que é pior porque você acredita que o código está certo. O que todo iniciante (alguns que já trabalham há vários anos na área) erra na programação é acreditar que se o código funcionar ele está certo. E isso está longe de ser verdade, se a pessoa não domina o que está fazendo e acha que está aprendendo porque o código funciona ela está fadada ao fracasso. E esse código funciona, mas está errado, porque não funcionará em todas situações.

Você está criando um laço involuntário, está chamando uma função que chama a função anterior. Isso chama-se [recursão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101) e se executava várias vezes provocará o que chama-se [*stack overflow*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101). Então não pode chamar `main()` ali, precisar retornar normalmente e controlar a repetição na própria `main()` através de um laço. O mesmo vale para outras chamadas de funções que vai criando um caminho maluco. As chamadas devem ser feitas de forma estruturadas, não pode chamar qualquer cosia em qualquer lugar, porque vai funcionar em exemplo simples, quando for fazer algo mais complexo fará igual porque foi o que aprendeu e terá problemas sérios.

Nem entrei no mérito de ter usado várias globais por não sabe usar funções, então não a use até aprender. Treinar o erro fará você fazer errado a vida inteira.

Se isso está confuso é porque pulou etapas e ainda não aprendeu sobre essas coisa, seria interessante voltar um pouco atrás, aprender esses conceitos todos antes de fazer algo mais complexo. Procure um material que ensina programação de forma estruturada. Especialmente em C não dá para aprender na base do "bumba meu boi", ou você aprende como as coisas funcionam ou aprenderá tudo errado.

Não adianta muito consertar o erro que o VS mostra, o resto continuará errado, e se for para ficar errado então é só ignorar o *warning*.