# Erro "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" com classes

Tags: javascript, classes, objetos

Oi, eu estou tentando usar orientação a objetos em JavaScript, mas deu o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at createVector2 (lms.html:101)
    at Vector2.<instance_members_initializer> (lms.html:95)
    at new Vector2 (lms.html:90)
    at createVector2 (lms.html:101)
    at Vector2.<instance_members_initializer> (lms.html:95)
    at new Vector2 (lms.html:90)
    at createVector2 (lms.html:101)
    at Vector2.<instance_members_initializer> (lms.html:95)
    at new Vector2 (lms.html:90)
    at createVector2 (lms.html:101)
```

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
class Vector2
{
   x = 0;
   y = 0;
   
   zero = createVector2(0, 0);
   screenScale = createVector2(1280, 720);
}

function createVector2(x, y)
{
   var vec2 = new Vector2();
   vec2.x = parseFloat(x);
   vec2.y = parseFloat(y);
   
   return vec2;
}
```

Mas quando eu executo pelo a função *createVector2*, ele causa o erro.
Alguém poderia me ajudar? Seria muito grato.

Comment: Você está chamando as funções recursivamente, é só seguir o fluxo de execução que verá que isso não tem fim: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda cara ;)